# В чем смысл условия во второй строке?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```
function addClass(obj, cls) {
  var classes = obj.className ? obj.className.split(' ') : [];

  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if (classes[i] == cls) return; // класс уже есть
  }

  classes.push(cls); // добавить

  obj.className = classes.join(' '); // и обновить свойство
}

var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
};

addClass(obj, 'new');
addClass(obj, 'open');
addClass(obj, 'me');
alert(obj.className) // open menu new me
```

По условию нужно создать функцию addClass(obj, cls), которая добавляет в список класс cls, но только если его там еще нет и она не должна добавлять лишних пробелов.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл условия - предотвратить ошибку, если `className` отсутствует.

```js
var obj = {}; // no className

var classes = obj.className ? obj.className.split(' ') : []; 
console.log(classes); // пустой массив (классов нет)
   
classes = obj.className.split(' '); // Ошибка
```

PS: Рекомендую воспользоваться [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = obj.className ? obj.className.split(' ') : [];
```

В `classes` нужно положить массив всех классов элемента.

Читаем как работает тернарный оператор `?:` - [ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA).

Если `obj.className` пуст, то возвращаем пустой массив `[]`;

Если там есть содержание то возвращаем результат действия [split](http://javascript.ru/string/split).

Функция split дробит строку на части превращая в массив, используя для разделения разделитель из аргумента.

Всю эту функцию можно переписать более коротко

```
obj.classList.add(cls);
```

Используя современный синтаксис языка и переменную `classList` у тега.